# Xcode 4.1 Dismiss Two ModalViewController at same time

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

Im doing a TabBarApplication, and a login screen presented with ModalViewController.
In the Login screen is the new registration button, that leads me to choose the account type and then leads me to fill a form with personal information.
I have also back buttons in Account type screen and in the Personal Information form.

Its like this:
A - Login Screen.
B - Account type.
C - Personal info form.

User goes this way: A->B->C

If the user press back at account type (B), I'm just dismissing it and done.

If the user press back at Personal info (C), I dismiss C and B view appears.

But the problem is that, if the user is successfully registered. I need to dismiss C and B at same time and go to A (login screen) and I can't do it.

Since B is parent to C, I just can't dismiss them both.

This way I call the new views:

```
ScreenUpdateAccountOuter *registerscreen = [[ScreenUpdateAccountOuter alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:registerscreen animated:YES];
```

And this way I dismiss them:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Appreciated some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegate methods.

I hope you have heard about Protocols and Delegates in iOS. To know more about that, [see here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

[Download](http://cl.ly/1b330P0U370r1u1R1Q09) this application and see how I have implemented.

Comment: You don't need to have navigation controller. If you have any doubt, pl. post that here.

Comment: Thank you a lot... Worked perfectly after checking out your code :)

Comment: See my answer below for the proper way to dismiss two modal view controllers as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Mind you this is pseudo code.

In C: create a bool and set it to yes.

In B:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    if (myBool == YES)
    {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. The problem with that is that: viewDidAppear is called only once when the user goes from A to B... When I put myBool = YES and dismiss C... viewDidAppear is not called anymore. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When on C, and you want to jump back to A, call dismissModalViewController on B, it will animate C out, and show A underneath. This is the behaviour with multiple modals stacked up like this.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

Might be a sloppy solution, but try adding a `BOOL` property to the second controller. And in `viewWillAppear` make a check. If it's `YES`, then just dismiss that controller. Make a property of second view in the third view and before switching from the second to the third view set that property to self. Then after finishing registration set that `BOOL` in the second controller to `YES`. After that the `viewWillAppear` of the second view should be called and because the `BOOL` is `YES` it should dismiss itself.

Hope you understood it :)

Comment: there is no navigationcontroller as you can see it uses "presentModalViewController"

Comment: Actually nothing happens. No errors, no movement. The button works perfectly, but this code doesn't do anything.
Thank you for help

Comment: my suggestion, just add UINavigationcontrol in the main window and set as hidden then call [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
may be it will work.